# Webshpere MQ redirect message to DLQ based on withdrawal counter

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, dead-letter

Is there a possibility in IBM WebSphere MQ to redirect message from queue to Dead Letter Queue (DLQ), when its withdrawal counter would be bigger than 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queue manager will NOT automatically move the messages to BOQUEUE or DLQ. It is typically done by the client or client application to route the messages which they are unable to process. MQ JMS and XMS clients have this capability. If your application uses any other MQ clients, then routing of messages will need to be done by your application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the MQ Dead letter handler. MQDLH is a great feature where you can have rules written and the discarded messages can be processed.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1204_gupta/1204_gupta.html

Comment: Yeah I know, but in the article you've mentioned there is only the way of dealing with messages that are in the DLQ, but there is no way of redirecting messages to DLQ. Am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry about that , would have any application putting this message to the DLQ , if you use an application which language to do you use. Do you use a BO queue from where you move the messages to say a DLQ after retries ...

Comment: I wanted to avoid having the third party application that redirects the message to DLQ, but only configure QM in the way that it redirects message to the DLQ when it's rejected by destination process. I've found something about the Blackout Treshold and Blackout Queue, but I'm not sure how it works, and how to configure them using WebSphere MQ Explorer.

Comment: The backout happens when the messages are rejected , the number of rejections is based on BO threshold. If the retries exceed the BO Threshold , they get moved to the BO Queue defined. if the BOQ cannot be written into the messages will be discarded or moved to DLQ  (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032280_.htm) . I am not sure if there is an automatic way to move this to DLQ , as usually the MQDLH needs to be filled in with reason of the failure.

Comment: I think the BO Queue will be enough in my case, and I've tried to configure it, but it does not work for me. Does the BO queue has to be of special type or, are there any other constraints?

Comment: It is just a local queue. You will have to alter your existing local queue to have a BO Queue and a BO Threshold. If the message gets rolled back , after the retry count mentioned in the threshold , the message should get moved to BO Queue